# Why Ubuntu appears in boot options after I uninstall it?

Tags: grub2, uninstall, windows-8, uefi

I'm new in this forum; I've got an Asus s56 laptop with Windows 8 installed and UEFI bios; I have to use Ubuntu to work, so i installed it on an external hard drive; Few days ago i had to uninstall Ubuntu, and when i entered the boot menu i realised that maybe i installed the boot loader in windows hard disk, because in the boot list there is the ubuntu option;if I try to boot from it ,the grub doesn't find the partition (and this is what I expect, because Ubuntu was on an external disk); somebody on this forum suggested to delete the directory EFI/ubuntu , but i don't find it in my EFI partition; so, the question is : how can i delete the unused boot option without making mistakes?

Thanks and sorry for the errors, I'm from Italy

Answer (score 0):

may be msconfig can help you. you can reduce seconds of waiting (from 30 to 3)

or you can use windows disk and recover boot loader. in command prompt BootRec.exe /FixBoot (if i am not wrong)

you must do it in recovery mode, from boot disk.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think that the `bootrec.exe` tool is useful only on BIOS-based computers. User210333's system is EFI-based, so the procedure is different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the command BootRec.exe /FixBoot in the command prompt of Windows 8, but it didn't work

Comment: you must do it in recovery mode, from boot disk.